# Java class inheritance in eclipse

Tags: java, inheritance

I am fairly new at programming (especially in java) and had a question regarding inheritance in java. I understand the syntax for inheritance (`class newPlayer extends Player`) but am wondering if all the source code or something has to be in the same folder or imported or something for java to detect it.

Im working on a school assignment and had to download the .java class file and inherit from it. I am also using eclipse to work on this project. Right now I'm just getting the message that I need to create a Player class. hope this all makes sense!! ANy help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the **exact** message you are getting? Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: based on `class newPlayer extends Player` it kind of seems like you want to create an instance of `Player`, but maybe not. If you do you just have to say `Player newPlayer = new Player();` But that wont get rid of your error.

Comment: [Your question has been answered here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869006/import-a-custom-class-in-java

Answer (score 1):

No, it has to only be on project's class path for the compiler and eclipse to see it.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for doing this? This is my first time doing this and I am a wee bit lost....

Answer (score 1):

'Ctrl+Shift o'  if its in your path this will add the import.

If your new be careful of extend v implements.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done both ways.  If class `Player` is not in the same package as `newPlayer`, then you need an `import` statement.  If they are in the same package you don't need one.