# How to reference enums in another class

Tags: java, enums

Here is the enum

```
class A {

    public A() {
    }
    public enum B{
        XYZ
        ABC
    }
    public enum c{
        DCE
    }
}
```

How should i call enum B and enum c in another class?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663834/in-java-are-enum-types-inside-a-class-static

Comment: My questions is how to decalre enum B in class c

Comment: Do you mean "declare" as in declare the enum or declare a type? As with nested static classes you write "package.Class.NestedClass" (`A.B` in your case) to access the type. But if you struiggle to use that Enum, maybe you should declare it top level in the first place?

Comment: class A {

    public A() {
    }
    public enum B{
        XYZ
        ABC
    }

Comment: SO now how do i decalre it in class B the enum B

Comment: You need a comma, pal.

Answer (score 2):

Import the Enum, use it.

```
import A.B;
...
B b = B.XYZ;
```

Comment: private B b; Can i do this?

Comment: Yeah, sure. If that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can call like following

```
A.B.XYX
A.c.DCE
```

Comment: How to declare enum clas A in another calss B

Comment: `class B { A.B e = A.B.XYZ; }`

Answer (score 0):

1.Just use class **B extends A** so the **class B can see all the Objects of class A** 
If you dont know how extend works see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

2.Also you can use **import** to import A class

- if you work in eclipse you should refer and the package name of A
- If you work in NetBeans something similar
- If you don't work(*you work on notepad..*) just use import A

  [Import a custom class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869006/import-a-custom-class-in-java)

  ```
  public class B extends A{
     //The class B can see the Objects of class A if they are not      **private** 
   }
  ```

What,why,and how enums work http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html