# can't find class in separated files

Tags: java, class, find

This is my first time doing java codes, and I am confused on this. I supposed to compile 2 files, the first is `Lingkaran.java` which contains `class lingkaran`, and the second is `MLingkaran.java` which is the `main file`. The `Lingkaran.java` compiles just fine, but when I tried to compile the `MLingkaran.java`, these errors came out.

> C:\Users\LENOVO PC>javac F:\SchoolSums-Praktikum\Semester4\PemrogramanBerbasisObjek\14.03.17\2\MLingkaran.java
>          F:\SchoolSums-Praktikum\Semester4\PemrogramanBerbasisObjek\14.03.17\2\MLingkaran.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>             lingkaran l = new lingkaran();
>             ^
>             symbol:   class lingkaran
>             location: class mLingkaran
>           F:\SchoolSums-Praktikum\Semester4\PemrogramanBerbasisObjek\14.03.17\2\MLingkaran.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>                   lingkaran l = new lingkaran();
>                                     ^
>             symbol:   class lingkaran
>             location: class mLingkaran
>         2 errors

The following are the source code:

**Lingkaran.java:**

```
class lingkaran {
    private double jari;
    private double luas;
    private double keliling;
    private double phi;

    public lingkaran(){
        this.phi = 3.14;
        this.jari = 10;
        this.keliling =  this.jari*2*this.phi;
        this.luas = this.phi * this.jari * this.jari ;
    }

    public double getLuas() {
        return this.luas;
    }

    public double getKeliling() {
        return this.keliling;
    }
}
```

and the MLingkaran.java:

```
class mLingkaran {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        lingkaran l = new lingkaran();

        System.out.println("keliling = " +l.getLuas());
        System.out.println("luas = " +l.getKeliling());
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't import the class and you should have a look at: http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions | Java class names should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: how do I import it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869006/import-a-custom-class-in-java | Please use the search function in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the other files to be able to use anything in them.

```
import <package>.Lingkaran;
```

If the file isn't in a package (it should be though), then you can leave the first part out.

Let's take the following project structure:

```
package1
    MLingkaran
    package2
        Lingkaran
```

Then in MLingkaran you need to use

```
import package1.package2.Lingkaran;
```

Comment: ummm.... i don't think that i should use package... my lecturer did it without "package" thing..
so what if i don't use it? is there a way without using the "package"?

Comment: @Ronaldo As I told you, there's a way, but then you have to okit the part before and including the dot. Your lecturer will probably get to packages eventually.

Comment: I tried to compile those again, now in eclipse IDE. it works, but I have to put those two in a project..
it seems that i eclipse automatically put both files in a same project.. don't know how though..
I'll try to repair the codes again, thanks for your advice :3